# Possible Hard Disk failure

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, hardware-failure, smart

I have a dual-boot laptop with Windows 10 on `/dev/sda1` and Ubuntu on `/dev/sda6`; recently, Windows will boot properly, but Ubuntu will not, saying the filesystem encountered errors and prompted me to run `fsck` manually:

- I ran `fsck` on `/dev/sda6`, following the on-screen instructions and selecting yes for all the incoming prompts; I observed the following error messages while selecting yes on all the overwrite prompts:

  ```
  ata1:00: status: { DRDY ERR }
  ata1.00: error {UNC }
  ```

  After a while, Ubuntu did boot with missing icons, but was a little slower than usual.

I am unsure if the hard drive is failing or what possible actions to take, but this is the S.M.A.R.T output for `/dev/sda6`:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MQ01ABD...
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100
Serial Number:    17T7C00QT
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 78360b89e
Firmware Version: AX1R4C
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Jul 31 11:55:24 2020 IST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x51) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 199) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0027   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   100   100   002    Pre-fail  Always       -       1720
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       35333
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0025   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   081   081   000    Old_age   Always       -       7739
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   253   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5545
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
185 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       65535
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       562
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       5
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   065   050   040    Old_age   Always       -       35 (Min/Max 25/35)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2796
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3866683
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   094   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       69078
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   065   050   040    Old_age   Always       -       35 (Min/Max 25/35)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       920
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       1

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 564 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 564 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7738 hours (322 days + 10 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 b0 e0 23 f7 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00f723e0 = 16196576

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 b0 e0 23 f7 40 00      00:34:57.725  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:34:57.724  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:34:57.723  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      00:34:57.722  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:34:57.722  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]

Error 563 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7738 hours (322 days + 10 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 70 e0 23 f7 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00f723e0 = 16196576

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 70 e0 23 f7 40 00      00:34:53.901  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:34:53.900  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:34:53.899  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      00:34:53.898  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:34:53.898  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]

Error 562 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7738 hours (322 days + 10 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 78 d8 23 f7 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00f723d8 = 16196568

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 78 d8 23 f7 40 00      00:34:50.076  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:34:50.076  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:34:50.075  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      00:34:50.074  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:34:50.073  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]

Error 561 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7738 hours (322 days + 10 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 f0 d8 23 f7 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00f723d8 = 16196568

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 f0 d8 23 f7 40 00      00:34:46.256  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:34:46.255  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:34:46.254  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      00:34:46.254  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:34:46.253  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]

Error 560 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7738 hours (322 days + 10 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 38 d8 23 f7 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00f723d8 = 16196568

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 38 d8 23 f7 40 00      00:34:42.432  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:34:42.431  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:34:42.430  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      00:34:42.430  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:34:42.429  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your drive is failing (SMART result notwithstanding). Take a backup, then buy a replacement disk.

Comment: how severe is the case, any estimate how much time, will it take for the hard drive to go completely unusable?

Comment: @DarkBlaze It's extremely severe, as the platters have been damaged, which is what the S.M.A.R.T output is showing.  Drive has 7739hrs on it and the physical damage occurred at 7738hrs, with a total of 564 hardware errors... dump the data off of it immediately and hope there's no critical data stored on the damaged sections of the platters.